# How to create a database replica in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 with years of data and hundreds of tables, stored procedures, views and jobs.

I want to create a replica of the database in the same server (it's clustered) for archiving purposes. I want to keep in the production database just up to 2 years of data, and everything older then that, remove it from the production DB and insert it into the archive database. I plan on doing that using an SSIS package.

I would like to know the best way to create the new database with all empty objects in it and any pitfalls, tricks, or any other thing I should watch for.

Thanks, and a happy new year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the data but just the schema this should help
[Script Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/)